# Finding latest android-server.apk

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I can't find the latest version of android-server.apk their [download page](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/list) says the page has moved but when I go there I can't find android-server.apk

what is their official page that I can find the latest download?

Answer (score 0):

On the same page, select **All Downloads** option from the search drop-down.
Type android-server.apk in the text field and hit the Search button.
You can download the apk file from the results.